# type of object 'NewsletterUsuario' has no len()

Tags: python, django, git, python-3.x

I'm new using django as a framework, I got a problem when I try to save a newsletter on my custom control_panel, I can save the message but the web crash and show me a typeError telling me about a class model I made 'NewsletterUsuario' but just on the custom control_panel, in django admin mode it works normally, the problem start to happen after I eliminate some files from a app that I did not want to use and even I did a git reset to a working version still get this similar typeError, here is my models, views and traceback:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class NewslettersUsuario(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    fecha_agregado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
        ('Published', 'Published')
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    body = models.TextField()
    email = models.ManyToManyField(NewslettersUsuario)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template

from .models import NewslettersUsuario, Newsletter
from .forms import NewslettersUsuarioSignUpForm, NewsletterCreacionForm
# Create your views here.
def newsletter_signup(request):
    form = NewslettersUsuarioSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if NewslettersUsuario.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            messages.warning(request,
            "Lo siento! este Correo ya existe.",
            'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
        else:
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request,
            "Tu e-mail a sido agregado!",
            'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')
            subject = "Gracias por uniter a nuestro Newsletter"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [instance.email]
            with open(settings.BASE_DIR + "/templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.txt")as f:
                signup_message = f.read()
            message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, body=signup_message, from_email=from_email, to=to_email)
            html_template = get_template("newsletters/sign_up_email.html").render()
            message.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
            message.send()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    template = 'newsletters/sign_up.html'

    return render(request, template, context)

def newsletter_unsubscribe(request):
    form = NewslettersUsuarioSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if NewslettersUsuario.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            NewslettersUsuario.objects.filter(email=instance.email).delete()
            messages.success(request,
            "Tu e-mail a sido eliminado.",
            "alert alert-success alert-dismissible")
            subject = "Haz sido dado de baja de nuestro Newsletter"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [instance.email]
            with open(settings.BASE_DIR + "/templates/newsletters/unsubscribe_email.txt")as f:
                signup_message = f.read()
            message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, body=signup_message, from_email=from_email, to=to_email)
            html_template = get_template("newsletters/unsubscribe_email.html").render()
            message.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
            message.send()
        else:
            messages.warning(request,
            "Lo siento pero no encontramos tu Correo.",
            "alert alert-warning alert-dismissible")
    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    template ='newsletters/unsubscribe.html'

    return render(request, template, context)
```

and Here is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/control/newsletter/

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'crispy_forms',
 'newsletters',
 'tutoriales']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Downloadudacity\Workplace 2\pjt_cook\env\src\newsletters\views.py" in control_newsletter
  80.                 send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[email], message= body,fail_silently=True)

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py" in send_mail
  60.     return mail.send()

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  294.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
  110.                 sent = self._send(message)

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in _send
  123.         recipients = [sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in email_message.recipients()]

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in <listcomp>
  123.         recipients = [sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in email_message.recipients()]

File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\DOWNLO~1\WORKPL~2\pjt_cook\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in sanitize_address
  103.         addr = parseaddr(addr)

File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\email\utils.py" in parseaddr
  224.     addrs = _AddressList(addr).addresslist

File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\email\_parseaddr.py" in __init__
  500.             self.addresslist = self.getaddrlist()

File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\email\_parseaddr.py" in getaddrlist
  252.         while self.pos < len(self.field):

Exception Type: TypeError at /control/newsletter/
Exception Value: object of type 'NewslettersUsuario' has no len()
```

hope you can help me understand why is this and get to a solution, thank you so much.

Comment: The error raised in `views.py` in a function `control_newsletter`. Please show the function.

Comment: oky i'll show you that function

Comment: https://jpst.it/1aAVp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the code:

```
for email in newsletter.email.all():
    send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[email], message= body,fail_silently=True)
```

In the loop every `email` is an instance of class `NewslettersUsuario` instead of an email address in text. Probably you need `email.email`:

```
for email in newsletter.email.all():
    send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[email.email], message= body,fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: oh wow and the wierd thing is that it was working even it has that ambiguos expression of mine, thank you so much  it worked perfectly.